# asp.net core 2.1 web app disabling https and enable http only

Tags: http, iis, https, asp.net-core-2.1

I was trying to enable http on a specific api controller in a .net core 2.1 web application. I have tried to disable https in startup.cs using the following code.

```
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                //  app.UseHsts();
            }
            //  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseHttpMethodOverride();
```

However, I am able to login to the web app and also use the http mode on all the controllers while running the web app in development mode from visual studio. When I install the web application on iis and configure the ddns in router. I am unable to login using the identity credentials.

I am able access the api controller methods through http while debugging and even able to access through localhost:iishttpPort. But when I try to login through http through ddns configuration login attempt is always failed. it works if I use https.

I need to disable the https and enable http only on a api controller.
Any help is appreciated.

[image: My IIS Bindings]

[image: My DDNS Configuration]

[image: My PORT Forwarding Rules]

Comment: Can you add an image of your iis bindings?

Comment: In IIS, if you don't specifically add https binding, the site uses http by default. Can you describe the problem of login in more detail?

Comment: added screenshots of iis bindings, ddns configuration and port forwarding rule for your reference. I am able to login locally but not through ddns. Even I have tried by removing https binding in iis and port forwarding but it did not help.